# IIS7: URL rewrite http://web1.com/web1/def.aspx to http://web1.com/def.aspx

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have to have my website stored in a subfolder of my domain root.  Is there a way to rewrite the URLs so that it doesn't appear to be stored in a subfolder?  It doesn't matter to me if this is done at the IIS level or in the web.config.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the routing engine that came out of the MVC project but is now a stand-alone feature of the .NET Framework?

Answer (score 1):

With IIS7, the way to go is probably the module that Microsoft themselves put out:
http://blogs.iis.net/ruslany/archive/2008/11/10/url-rewrite-module-release-to-web.aspx

In previous releases, there were various workarounds with different downsides/costs:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Comment: Here is a tutorial on how to set it up. http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to go with an ISAPI filter, we've had good experiences with [Ionic's Isapi Rewrite](http://www.codeplex.com/IIRF). And it's free (beer and speech).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the [ManagedFusion Url Rewriter](http://www.managedfusion.com/products/url-rewriter/) on my blog. I like it because it doesn't need to be installed at the server level.

Answer (score 0):

You can presumably get the behavior you want by using an ISAPI filter.

Google for: rewrite ISAPI filter and you will find some prebuilt examples to try and see what works best for you.